# call values that have a common key in Lua

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, lua

1Is there a way to write a function to multiply two values based on only the fact that they have the same key? Here is some psudocode for what I have in mind:

```
operation = {a=12, b=7, c=31}
operator1 = {a=0.5}
operator2 = {a=0.7}
operator3 = {b=0.3}

function Operate(x)
  return x.common_key * operation.common_key
end

print (Operate (operator1)) 
print (Operate (operator3))

--->   6
--->   2.1
```

This code of course doesn't work, because "common_key" isn't a real thing. It is a stand-in for whatever the function's argument has in common with the "operation" dictionary. In this case, it would be "a", so the function would multiply "operator1.a" and "operation.a" if it could.

Comment: `function Operate(x) local k,v = next(x) return operation[k]*v end`

Comment: This works perfectly! I just have no idea how. I'll be reading up on the "next" function in the manuals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pairs` function to iterate over a table, allowing you to inspect what keys it has available. Additionally, you can access tables with t[k] notation instead of t.name if k is the "name" string and lua tables return `nil` if you access a key that it doesn't have.

```
function find_common_keys(t1, t2)
    for k,v1 in pairs(t1) do
       local v2 = t2[k]
       if v2 ~= nil then
          print("Found match", k, v1, v2)
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: Because there will only ever be one value for operator, I can't justify a loop if it's only ever going to run once. what about something like return x[1] * operation[x[1]]?

Comment: @etothepowerofx: ipairs uses the `next` internally to iterate over the table. You can use it if you know that your table will only have a single key. Other than that, using next / ipairs is the only way to see what keys are part of a table. Personally, I would either change the input format to something easier to work with (say, `operator1 = {key="a", value=0.5}`) or I would run the loop once and cache the result somewhere.

Comment: After reading the manual section on next and pairs for the 27th time your advice finally clicked.  Thanks!

Comment: @etothepowerofx: hahaha, sorry I couldn't make it easy to understand the first time :)